# Label callouts problem

Tags: qgis, labeling

[image]

I'm using QGIS 3.34, I'm having difficulty with the option of label callouts. As part of my work, I want to produce a map with buildings and their addresses. There are buildings that have several addresses and in order to identify them with a line, I chose the label callout option. However, by doing this, the lines connect labels having the same address, but not on the same street.

How can I make each address go to its own line?

Comment: Please provide your full label settings, incl. all relevant tabs.